# Sum all numbers of all the cells in tableview ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am looking how to make a sum of all the cells in my tableview.

Each cell crated by user have a number on a label. This number is diferent in each cell.

How can i make the sum of all the numbers in all the cells?

I think its important to say im using Core Data.

Thanks, hope anyone can help me.
Be free to ask any other detail.

EDIT:

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedYear;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fondo.png"]];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
}


- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Years"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Years.name = Blah"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"subject"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"My Cell";

    MarksCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MarksCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Year *years = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.celltitlelabel.text = years.subject;


    return cell;


}
```

Comment: What didn't work with the answer from yesterday?

Comment: You axplained me how do do it with an array but i didnt get it. I dont have any array im using core data, sorry, and thanks for worry about it

Comment: You can get an array of the objects from core data. How are you getting the data to update your table view (fetched results controller)?

Comment: Yes, i use fetchresult of my entity. How can i make the array?thanks

Comment: The fetched results controller has a property `fetchedObjects` which returns all the objects.

Comment: i edited with the code where cells are made

Comment: Hopefully `subject` is text, and `Year` has another property which is the number?

Comment: year is call the entity and the atribute with the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Year` entity has an attribute `value` which is an `NSNumber`:

```
NSArray *myNumbers = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
NSNumber *sum = [myNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"];
```

Comment: thanks, when i prove it i tell u my experience, i am fixing something. Something, its correct or u use @"@sum.value". Is .value a property? becaouse is not in other place of the code

Comment: Yes, you haven't shown code for the `Year` entity and you can't add strings (or not without additional code anyway), so `value` is the name I've guessed for the number property.

Comment: i did it :) Thanks you a lot for your patience